# Where is the toggle for 'Limit Selection To Visible'?

Tags: modeling, vertices, select

In Edit mode, in the Solid mode, I cannot seem to find the toggle for 'limit selection to visible'. Sometimes I just want to grab all the vertices I know are in an area quickly, to then scale then in the X, Y or Z quickly. Can I turn 'limit selection to visible' off? Do I need to go into XRAY mode to do this every time?
[image: XRAY mode - vertices CAN be selected]

[image: Solid mode - vertices only selectable in XRAY mode]

Comment: If it's the transparency that you don't like, you an adjust that in the shading menu.

Answer (score 8):

That is what Toggle X-ray does. Control if you can select through objects or not. It shows vertices that otherwise would not be visible, and allows you to select them.

[image]

Comment: this works in 3.3 version as well

Comment: this does not allow for other modes like weight paint.